# Problem with inserting values into a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I want to create a Binary Search Tree, but I'm coming across an error message.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

Class 1 (the insert part):

```
public class Tree{
    
    public insert(Item item) {
        if (look != null) {
            System.out.println("Number already exists");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            root = insertAsRoot(item, root);
        }
    }
    
    private Node insertAsRoot(Itemitem, TreeNode h) {
        if (h == null) {
            Node node = new Node (item);
            return node;
        } 
        if (Math.random()*(h.N+1) < 1.0) {
            h = insertT(item, h);
        }
            
        if (item.key() < h.item.key()) {
            h.setLeft(insertAsRoot(item, h.getLeft()));
        } else {
            h.setRight(insertAsRoot(item, h.getRight()));
        }
        h.N++;
        return h;
    }
    
    private Node  insertT(Item item, Node h) {
        if (item.key() < h.item.key()) {
            h.setLeft(insertT(item, h.getLeft())); 
            h = rotR(h);
            } 
        else {
            h.setRight(insertT(item, h.getRight()));
            h = rotL(h); 
        }
        return h;
    }
    
    private Node rotR(Node h) {      
        Node x = h.getLeft();
        h.setLeft(x.getRight()); 
        x.setRight(h); 
        return x;
    }
    
    private Node rotL(Node h) {      
        Node x = h.getRight();
        h.right = x.left;
        x.left = h;
        return x;
    }
```

I can insert the first node in the tree (which becomes the root node), but after trying to insert  the second node this message appears:

"Cannot read file item because "h" is null"

If anyone can think of the problem, please tell me, I'm stuck!

Comment: `insertT` will keep calling itself until it arrives at a `h == null` at which point it goes splat. I think you need some condition under which it would not call itself again and just do something/nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the error is that your `insertT` function performs recursion without checking for the base case, which is when `h` is `null`. In that case you should actually create the node and return it.

```
    private TreeNode insertT(int item, TreeNode h) {
        if (h == null) { // Base case!
            return new TreeNode(item);  // Must create the node for the item
        }
        if (item.key() < h.item.key()) {
            h.setLeft(insertT(item, h.getLeft()));
            h = rotR(h);
        }
        else {
            h.setRight(insertT(item, h.getRight()));
            h = rotL(h); 
        }
        return h;
    }
```

Not related to the error, but `insertAsRoot` seems to make a random choice to either insert the new node using the `insertT` algorithm, so that the new node will end up at the root, *OR* to have the node inserted elsewhere, using recursive calls of `insertAsRoot`.  But your code might do *both*, and that is not intended.

So put the second option in an `else` block:

```
        if (Math.random()*(h.N+1) < 1.0) {
            h = insertT(item, h);
        } else if (item.key() < h.item.key()) {
//        ^^^^
            h.setLeft(insertAsRoot(item, h.getLeft()));
        } else {
            h.setRight(insertAsRoot(item, h.getRight()));
        }
```

The maintenance of the `N` field will need more attention. I think you didn't yet focus on that, since this field will need updates during rotations, and backtracking out of `insertT`, ...etc. I'll leave that for your further inspection.